How to improve a pagination query in mysql
How to improve my query where I have used offset in mysql. I am trying to make pagination.
I have a database there I have more then 800k data for a single column.
Example:
My table data like:
-----------------------------------
|id   | ip_to   | ip_from  | country |

When I run a query like
SELECT * FROM ipdetails WHERE cournty= 'US' LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 800000;

It takes more then 20 second.
I have already create index with country
How can I solve this in this problem. I want to make it fast
You can test it lively.
https://ip.team71.link/public/find-by-country-code?countryCode=US&page=830

I don’t understand why some people are down voting. It's a big query. It has huge things to know.

You can test it lively., a fiddle such as dbfiddle.uk would be a great example of a testing environment. When asking performance questions always include table description and execution plan.

If id is the primary key, then try:
SELECT i.*
FROM ( SELECT id FROM ipdetails WHERE cournty= 'US' LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 800000 ) x
INNER JOIN ipdetails i ON i.id = x.id;

It is faster for high offset values, because it can store more records in the server cache and the temporary table is much smaller. I use this kind of select for example with a table with 25000 records and 50 columns. If the offset is about 20000, the execution is about 2.5x faster.

It’s taking only 0.37s now

Comma separated join syntax it's 20+ years old, better switch to proper join syntax. And limit without order by is pointless even if MySQL default is ASC
